# I am trying to extract the rows with the same x values from two different files in matlab, how can I do it?

Tags: matlab

To be more clear, what I want is to generate file3 from file1 but with the x values in file 2.

Example:

```
 file 1:                  
 x1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]'
 y1=[11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00]'      

 file 2:                  
 x2=[3 4 5 8 9]'
 y2=[333 444 555 888 999]'

 file 3:                  
 x2=[3 4 5 8 9]'
 y2=[33 44 55 88 99]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) to find which values of x1 are in x2, and where they're located.

```
x1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]' 
y1=[11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00]'

x2=[3 4 5 8 9]' 
y2=[333 444 555 888 999]'



x3 = x2;
y3 = y1(ismember(x1,x2))

y3 =
    33
    44
    55
    88
    99
```